# How can I merger multiple .CSV files with same column names but each file has different dates?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have n-numbers of .CVS files of stocks profit loss data. Each .CVS file contains two columns -  Symbols and P&l. I want to make a master .CVS file where one column will be Symbols and then n- numbers of columns with P&l data having column name as the file name i.e. dates.
like.....
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "C:/Users/Arunava Datta/Desktop/trendline_equity/"
file_names = glob.glob(path+"*.csv")
names = []
for file_name in file_names:
    name = (os.path.basename(file_name))[:-4]
    names.append(name)
names
new_list = ["Symbol"] + names

df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=new_list)
df
```

I have developed the code partly.....can you people guide me rest of the part??

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't very clear. If you provide an example dataset (not a complete csv file but a "toy" dataframes that look like them), you are more likely to get an answer

Comment: how to give each separate dataframe a different date ? the csv file name contains the date ?

Comment: @khaled koubaa..file names like...21.09.22.csv, 22.09.22.csv, 23.09.22.csv......which contain trading data.......i want to make a single master CSV sheet.

Comment: @slymore I have added a picture for your better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an initial (empty) dataframe
2. Make a list of all `n` .csv files
3. Import them using a for loop and merge them with the initial dataframe, make sure that you merge on `Symbol` and that the new column name is the name of the used .csv file. Note that for the first dataframe you do not need to merge as there is nothing to merge with.

Good luck!

Comment: Shall try and give you feedback.

Comment: @T C Molenaar I have developed some part and then stuck .....can you guide me rest of the part????